# Hook to AppDomain.UnhandledException event from unmanaged code

Tags: c++, events, hosting, clr

I have a CLR hosting app, written in unmanaged C++.
I want to subscribe to AppDomain.UnhandledException event from unmanaged C++ code.

The imported AppDomain interface has the following method:

```
HRESULT add_UnhandledException (struct _UnhandledExceptionEventHandler *value);
```

Where UnhandledExceptionEventHandler defined as:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("84199e64-439c-3011-b249-3c9065735adb"))
_UnhandledExceptionEventHandler : IDispatch {};
```

I do not understand how to use this handler to connect it my callback function.
So, the question is how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen anyone doing it, but it might help you to consider the following:

1. a managed delagate isn't a "simple" callback in the c++ sence, it inherits from the clr-object, code i have seen in c++ hooking events was always managed c++.
2. after the unhandled exception handler is triggered what happens next depends on the clr policy settings (see 3.)

   1. either the process is terminated (default)
   2. the appdomain unloaded
   3. or the clr disabled
   4. swallow the exception (behavior of clr in  .net 1.x)
3. you can change the default action to 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 through the IHostPolicyManager
4. let's say you set the policy to unload or disable, you can use IActionOnCLREvent to setup a callback on unloaded/disabled.
5. with 3) and 4) you can setup your system

   1. to cleanup/log/save (what ever you need) in managed code in your UnhandledExceptionHandler
   2. you get notified of the unload of your appdomain in unmanaged code ... and do what ever you still need to do.
6. assuming this is not enough (your unmanaged code needs to know some details of the exception) you could define com interfaces (see idl sample below); your managed application implements IMyApplication and your unmanaged code IMyApplicationSink when you setup your appdomain you pass in the unmanaged implementation IMypplicationSink (your hook), the managed application has to call that hook in the managed unhandledexception eventhandler:

   ```
   interface IMyApplicationSink : IUnknown
   {
       HRESULT UnhandeledExceptionCallback(
       [in] BSTR aString,
       [in] short aNumber,
       [in] SAFEARRAY( BYTE ) someBinaryData);
   }

   interface IMyApplicationControl : IUnknown
   {
       HRESULT OnStart(
       [in] IPhotonApplicationSink *sink);
   }
   ```

   Note: for details on how to get the custom com interface see "Implement IHostControl::SetAppDomainManager" of "Customizing the Microsoft .NET Framework Common Language Runtime" (currently parts free readable [here](http://flylib.com/books/en/4.331.1.40/1/))
7. if you are not in control of the managed application, load first an application which is in your control - the default appdomain - the unhandled exception handler will be called there too (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx))
8. if you set the policy to swallow (2.4) your unmanaged code won't be notified the clr will keep going - you could of course combine this with the custom com interface (6.)